# Find filenames containing a phrase

Tags: powershell, filenames

Simple question, how does a person create a list of files that contain a certain phrase in the filename only?  I can run this on my files and does the job but also scans the contents:

```
Get-childItem -recurse | select-string "Document1" -List | export-csv "C:\temp\results.csv"
```

Looked at the list of parameters and can't find one that could do it for me ;-(

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path '*document1*', '*othersearchterm*, '*andanother*' -Recurse`

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-Filter` option, i.e. to filter files which have a filename starting with *foo*:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "foo*"
```